# Make and answer PJSIP/PJSUA2 Python calls

Tags: python, voip, pjsip, pjsua2

I'm trying to develop a code in Python that first makes a sip call to an extension and when the call is answered it plays an audio file, I managed to authenticate the account but the call is not made, below is my code, me too I want to implement call reception in sequence, I can even see the call arriving but I don't know how to configure it to answer. and I would like the community's help to adjust the code below to serve as a basic reference for authentication, originating calls and receiving calls using Python.

```
import pjsua2 as pj
import time


class Account(pj.Account):
    def onRegState(self, prm):
        print("***OnRegState: " + prm.reason)
        if prm.code == 200:
            make_call()


class MyCall(pj.Call):
    def __init__(self, acc, dest_uri):
        pj.Call.__init__(self, acc)
        self.dest_uri = dest_uri

    def on_state(self):
        if self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_CALLING:
            print("Chamando", self.dest_uri)
        elif self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_INCOMING:
            print("Chamada recebida de", self.info().remote_uri)
            self.answer()
        elif self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_EARLY:
            pass
        elif self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONNECTING:
            pass
        elif self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_CONFIRMED:
            print("Chamada conectada. Reproduzindo áudio...")
            self.start_audio("testeaudio.wav")
        elif self.info().state == pj.PJSIP_INV_STATE_DISCONNECTED:
            print("Chamada desconectada, motivo:", self.info().last_reason)
            self.delete()

# pjsua2 test function
def pjsua2_test():
    # Create and initialize the library
    ep_cfg = pj.EpConfig()
    ep = pj.Endpoint()
    ep.libCreate()
    ep.libInit(ep_cfg)

    # Create SIP transport. Error handling sample is shown
    sipTpConfig = pj.TransportConfig()
    sipTpConfig.port = 5064
    ep.transportCreate(pj.PJSIP_TRANSPORT_UDP, sipTpConfig)
    # Start the library
    ep.libStart()

    acfg = pj.AccountConfig()
    acfg.idUri = "sip:1523@sbc.dominio.cloud:5064"
    acfg.regConfig.registrarUri = "sip:sbc.dominio.cloud:5064"
    cred = pj.AuthCredInfo("digest", "*", "9999", 0,  "9999#")
    acfg.sipConfig.authCreds.append(cred)
    # Create the account
    acc = Account()
    acc.create(acfg)
    # Here we don't have anything else to do..
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print("Encerrando chamada...")
        if acc.calls.count > 0:
            call = acc.calls[0]
            call.hangup()
            time.sleep(2)
        ep.libDestroy()

def make_call():
    dest_uri = "sip:1571@sbc.dominio.cloud:5064"  # Ramal 1571
    acc = pj.Account()
    call = MyCall(acc, dest_uri)
    call.make_call(dest_uri)

#
# main()
#
if __name__ == "__main__":
    pjsua2_test()
```

Comment: Did you manage to get further on this, Rodrigo. Looking eagerly for a working python recipe myself. Will share it if/when I succeed. Some things I see in your code right away: For one, I see that you should accept the call from the Account.onIncomingCall. There are a few examples around. Secondly, I needed to exchange timer() with ep.libHandleEvents(1000) to make sure the library runs smoothly. It also provides much more relevant debug messages for some reason.

Comment: Can you share the logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try call construction like this

````
   ci = call.getInfo()
   mi = ci[0]
   m = call.getMedia(mi.index)
   am = pj.AudioMedia.typecastFromMedia(m)
   wav_player = pj.AudioMediaPlayer()
   wav_player.createPlayer('path/to/audio.wav', True)
   wav_player.startTransmit(am)
   play_media = True```
````